# Non-Functional writing and getting ArraryList Android

Tags: java, android, file, listview

I use the following code to load and write list to a file. This was working when I closed the application(backgrounded it) and restarted it, but that stopped working now, and I do not recall changing a thing. Furthermore, the list is definitely not saving if I reboot the phone.

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> painItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

String serfilename;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addscreen);
    // getPainItems from the saved file
    if (loadListFromFile((ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) painItems) != null)
        painItems = loadListFromFile((ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) painItems);

    serfilename = "hello";

....


private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> loadListFromFile(
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> masterlistrev) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(serfilename);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        masterlistrev = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) ois
                .readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return masterlistrev;
}

private void writeListToFile(
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> masterlistrev, Context ctx,
        String filename) {

    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = ctx.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(masterlistrev);
        oos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    writeListToFile((ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) painItems,
            getApplicationContext(), serfilename);
}
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    writeListToFile((ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) painItems,
            getApplicationContext(), serfilename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if you're not closing your file correctly. Place the Close() method call of your streams in a finally block. Close your ObjectInputStream aswell.

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
try {
  fos = ctx.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
  oos.writeObject(masterlistrev);
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
  oos.Close();
}
```

Comment: Do you think that my OnDestroy() and OnStop() method overrides are formatted correctly? Will they properly save the list even when the phone is rebooted or backgrounded? Thanks for the tip, i'll try it.

Comment: They appear to be, try to write to a log file or similar to see when they are called etc.

Comment: should I writeListToFile() before calling the super method in these onStop() and onDestroy()?

Comment: writeListToFile() should be placed afterwards.

Comment: okay. the only reason I was wondering is because maybe the device will carry out and destroy the activity, and then the operation will not be executed(it may not be able to write the file)

Comment: should I also use the finally block in the write and load methods?

Comment: Yes, you should. Atleast when you are debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the filename before you try to load the data in the `onCreate(...)`.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addscreen);

    serfilename = "hello";

    // getPainItems from the saved file
    if (loadListFromFile((ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) painItems) != null)
        painItems = loadListFromFile((ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) painItems);

    ....
```

Comment: thank you; i have done this, although this does not seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here my test class:

```
private List<HashMap<String, String>> painItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
private static final String serfilename = "hello";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addscreen);

    // getPainItems from the saved file
    loadListFromFile();

    // here are my tests:
    // at the first run a hash map will be added and with the onStop saved
    // at the next runs the data will be read and logged
    if (painItems.size() == 0) {
        painItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("a", "b");
        painItems.add(map);
    } else {
        Log.d("test", "Key a: " + (String)(painItems.get(0).get("a")));
    }
}

private void loadListFromFile() {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try {
        fis = openFileInput(serfilename);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        painItems = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>)ois.readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    try {
        ois.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    try {
        fis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}

private void writeListToFile() {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        fos = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(serfilename, MODE_PRIVATE);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(painItems);
        oos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    try {
        oos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    try {
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    writeListToFile();
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    writeListToFile();
}
```