# Specific OnItemClick Intent Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onitemclicklistener

I want the following to happen (a simple idea): I click an Add button in my main activity, enter some info(into EditText boxes), and go back to the main screen. Here, I want to display a list, with just two titles(not all the info). When I click that list Item, I want to show the corresponding saved info for that item. Therefore, each item's info is going to be different.

When I do this, I use startActivityForResult() from the main screen then back. This works perfectly for one item. When I add another item, the problem arises. No matter which item I click, the info displayed is the same. In short, I need to find a way to save that info unique to each item.

As of now, I have the following code snippet :

```
 //After I add all the information in the second intent

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == 1) {
        //these display in the list (Each list item has two textfields,row1 and row 2)

        row1 = data.getStringExtra("com.painLogger.row1");
        row2 = data.getStringExtra("com.painLogger.row2");

           //below is the other info entered

        painLevelString = data.getStringExtra("com.painLogger.painLevel");
        painLocation = data.getStringExtra("painLocation");
        timeOfPainString = data.getStringExtra("com.painLogger.painTime");
        textTreatmentString = data
                .getStringExtra("com.painLogger.treatment");
        addItem();
    }
}

    //When I click the item-- this is the info that is not unique...
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Item1.class);
    intent.putExtra("com.painLogger.painLevel", painLevelString);
    intent.putExtra("com.painLogger.painTime" , timeOfPainString);
    intent.putExtra("com.painLogger.treatment", textTreatmentString);
    intent.putExtra("painLocation", painLocation);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

// **EDIT :ADD ITEM CODE ADDED**

```
private void addItem() {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("row_1", row1);
    map.put("row_2", row2);
    painItems.add(map);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

//**EDIT: some defining **

```
SimpleAdapter adapter;
List<HashMap<String, String>> painItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

I can understand why this is occuring-- every time I click an item, the intent is putting the last extra, meaning the last object's info added. How do I make each OnItemClick unique? I suspect I will have to use the position variable.

Comment: where are you saving to?

Comment: Where do you save the information for each item?

Comment: unfortunately, I think this is the problem. I only save the array list, as shown in my previous question(this is working, at the moment):http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839965/non-functional-writing-and-getting-arrarylist-android/6840035#6840035. So how would I go about saving each item's info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two recommendations:

Pass the data to your method instead of using class fields:

```
addItem(String row1, String row2...){...}
```

Also, you want to grab your data out of the map:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Item1.class);
    intent.putExtra("com.painLogger.painLevel", painItems.get(position).get("row_1"));
    intent.putExtra("com.painLogger.painTime" , painItems.get(position).get("row_2"));
    intent.putExtra("com.painLogger.treatment", painItems.get(position).get("row_3"));
    intent.putExtra("painLocation", painItems.get(position).get("row_4"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

You will of course need to put "row_3" and "row_4" into the map as you create it, which I believe you are not yet doing.

DMon suggested in a comment in a different answer that you create a class that represents your data, and he is right, it is much better design and helps save on these problems. To do so you will need to look at the Parcelable interface to be able to pass your class through Intents.  Your design will work, but it will be very difficult to understand for the next guy (including you in 6 months) and much more difficult to extend.

Comment: the thing is, I don't want to display the other things in each item(row). If I put row_3 and row_4 in the map, will I have to display them?

Comment: thank you so much. problem solved. for some reason your solutions always seem to work. I cannot express the relief I'm feeling now :P

Comment: mbarnes, Is there a way to put an image in the map? I want to do the same thing, except with an image, not a string...

Comment: HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

Comment: how can I do the same thing with a picture? Obviously, I cannot use painItems.add(pictureMap), where pictureMap would be the HashMap<String, Object> map....? Is there another way to add it to painItems?

Comment: map.put("picture", image_object); you will need to cast the it back to the correct object when you read it out.  This is exactly the kind of extension that makes you want to create a custom class to store in that List instead of the HashMap. Create a PainItem object. Give it fields like String painLevel; and String imageURL; then you will need to make a number of changes like: addItem(PainItem thisitem){ painItems.add(thisitem); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();) We are outside of the scope of this question though. Theres not enough space in a comment. You may have enough to go on though.

Comment: BTW storing the image like that can really eat your memory if you have a lot of items in your backing List.  It is better to store the URL of the image as a String and create an asychronous get called from getView() in the adapter. It is a complex pattern and there are examples that do it included in the SDK if I remember correctly. You wont know you need it until your program goes in the field and it starts locking up because someone using it for a while are having it load 2000 images into the heap.

Comment: Can you please take a look at my question @ stackoverflow.com/questions/…...? I am having an issue with saving and loading a bitmap image. Another answer opportunity for you, @mbarnes! :P

Comment: The link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861820/saving-picture-to-a-file-and-retrieving-it/6861866#6861866

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing your `addItem()` code, how are you adding the items to the list? Presumably you have an adapter where the values are stored, if so, then in the `onItemClick()`, you would do `painItem = adapter.getItem(position)`. You would then assemble your Intent using this `painItem` object.

Comment: I am not saving each item's info. Please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839965/non-functional-writing-and-getting-arrarylist-android/6840035#6840035 to see how I am saving the list itself. I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me do the things you outlined... If you could give me sample code, that would be really helpful

Comment: As it is right now, you could use  `Map painItem = painItems.get(position)` and retrieve your data from there, however, using a `List<HashMap<String, String>>` sounds like a bad idea. Instead, try creating your own object class and saving/loading the data from there.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is occurring is that the information sent in onItemClick is *in no way* based on which row was clicked - It's based on the most recent values set in onActivityResult, which are set by the *last* item clicked.

One solution would be to use a modified version of the ViewHolder pattern to attach row-specific values to the View, and then in onItemClick retrieve those values using view.getTag.  Good sample code for the ViewHolder pattern can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html).  It's typically for storing Views so that they're not continually recreated & re-inflated, but it can also be used for passing values to click handlers without needing to keep track of member variable state.

Comment: could you please provide sample code for my instance? I am not quite sure what you are talking about...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html  Covers it.  Basically you stash a bunch of data in an object, attach that object to the row's value as a "tag" using the view.setTag(Object o) method, and then from onClick use getTag to retrieve it.